# How to create a sliding div animation when hover and text are aligned

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to create a html document, where whenever the user hovers over a text, then the div besides it slide up and the one below slides up as well.

For example, right now i have the following:

[image]

If the user hovers over the top half portion, then "**Address**" would slide upwards replacing **Name** and **Name** would slide upwards as well, disappearing from the div.

An example scenario would be this:

[image]

By default Name would be beside "Hover Me", but if the user hovers over, then Name would slide upwards disappearing from the div, and Address would slide upwards and take over the Name position.

Would appreciate some help on this.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
    border: 3px solid #194a50;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 20%;
    width: 50%;
}

.top {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1vw;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.bottom {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}

.slider_text {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.address {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.name {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "outer">
    <div class = "top">
      Hover Me
        <div class = "slider_text">
          <div class = "address">Name</div>
          <div class = "name">Address</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "bottom">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
    border: 3px solid #194a50;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 20%;
    width: 50%;
}

.top {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1vw;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.top:hover .address {
    opacity: 1;
    top: -20px;
}

.top:hover .name {
    opacity: 0;
    top: -20px;
}

.bottom {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}

.slider_text {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.address {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    top: 0;
}

.name {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "outer">
    <div class = "top">
      Hover Me
        <div class = "slider_text">
          <div class = "name">Name</div>
          <div class = "address">Address</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "bottom">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the below snippet I have used transition with negative margin top, when you hover on div.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
    border: 3px solid #194a50;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 20%;
    width: 50%;
}

.top {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1vw;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.bottom {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}

.slider_text {
    height: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.top .slider_text div{
  height:100%;
  margin-top:0;
  transition: margin-top .3s ease-out;
}
.top:hover .slider_text div:first-child{
  margin-top:-10px;
  transition: margin-top .3s ease-out;
}
.address {

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.name {

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "outer">
    <div class = "top">
      Hover Me
        <div class = "slider_text">
          <div class = "address">Name</div>
          <div class = "name">Address</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "bottom">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```